# Enforce rails to close image_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm rendering an image_tag in a html.erb page, but the `<img>` tag is not closed. I'm getting
`<img alt="my_src" src="my_src">` instead of `<img alt="my_src" src="my_src" />`

The code looks like `<%= image_tag( 'my_src.png') %>`

Is there a way to enforce rails to close it?

Comment: you should show the code that you use to render the image.

Comment: Html5 doesn't require the closing slash.

Answer (score 0):

Rails (both `3` and `4`) closes the `img` tag by default. You must be doing something wrong. Anyway, you can use below method to generate `img` tag if `image_tag` was not working properly.

```
tag("img", {:src => "my_src.png"}, false)
```